# non-virtual destructors in c++ with override

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor

Yes I have seen a lots of posts about using the keywords **virtual** and **override** for destructors in C++. I also think I understand the usage:

- if a base class has a virtual destructor and a derived class overrides it, if the signatures are different, the program will not compile due to override.

However I am wondering - or I have seen it also several times in someones code, that it is used like this:

```
class Base
{
   public:
          ~Base();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
         ~Derived() override;
};
```

Does this override on a destructor of a non-virtual function in the base class actually has any impact on the program / compiling or anything? Or is it just used wrongly in that case?

Comment: That will not compile.

Comment: GCC: `error: 'Derived::~Derived()' marked 'override', but does not override`

Comment: [Your code does not compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xaI4PxGJRNPVUGjP)

Comment: What will not compile? And why, because over "override"?

Comment: "What will not compile?" umm... your code

Comment: Oh ok, maybe I have overseen this: if the Base class derives from another class, say **SuperBase** class - which has a virtual destructor, then the destructor of **Base** would be virtual without using the keyword right?

Comment: @malajedala yes, you don't have to repeat the "virtual" keyword in derived classes, although I would recommend doing so (to avoid exactly the kind of confusion you just had).

Comment: @Cedric thank you, maybe I missed that part, that would explain a lot.

Comment: @bolov thanks for useless commenting

Comment: @malajedala I am sorry, what?

Comment: Re: "if a base class has a virtual destructor and a derived class overrides it, if the signatures are different ..." -- the signatures cannot be different. A destructor takes no arguments and has no return type.

Answer (score 2):

You code doesn't compile because `Base::~Base` is not virtual.

> Oh ok, maybe I have overseen this: if the Base class derives from
> another class, say SuperBase class - which has a virtual destructor,
> then the destructor of Base would be virtual without using the keyword
> right?

Correct. If a method is virtual in a base class, then the method in the child class with the same name and same signature will also be implicitly virtual. `virtual` keyword can be omitted.

A good practice is to always use the keyword `override` on a method intended to override. This has two big advantages: it makes it clear to a human reader that the method is virtual and overrides and it avoid some bugs where the method is indented to override, but it silently doesn't (e.g. `const` mismatch).

Destructors are a special case in the sense that that they override a parent virtual destructor, even if they have different names.

Comment: Although this is all correct, you could add a comment about the "special destructor case" since they can be overridden (and virtual) despite having "different names".